# Recursive serialization method

Tags: c#, recursion, xml-serialization

I really need your help.

Actually, I read some files from a path and I serialize them. Until now, nothing special.
NOW: I have main files and also sub files (with new content) like in my example:

```
disktest.xml // Main file
disktest.1.xml  //Sub file
disktest.2.xml //Sub file
```

myFile class looks like this:

```
public class myFile 
{
  // Some XmlArguments like name, blablabla (xml elements)
  [XmlAttribute]
  public string Name {get; set;}
  [XmlAttribute]
  public string Version {get; set;}
  [XmlAttribute]
  public string Description{get; set;}
  ... 

  // And a list of my subfiles
  [XmlIgnore]
  public List<myFile> SubFiles {get; set;}

} 

public myFile()
{
  name = "";
  ... 
  SubFiles = new List<myFile>();
}
```

Like this I get all files from my path and I serilize them by using LoadFile()

```
// Read all Files and deserialize them
List<string> allfiles = Directory.GetFiles("path", "pattern").ToList();

List<myFile> files= allfiles.Select(f => myFile.LoadFile(f)).ToList();


public static myFile LoadFile(string fileName)
{
     myFile ret = new myFile();

     try
     {                  
         using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
         {
             XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(myFile ));
             ret = (myFile )ser.Deserialize(sr);
         }

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          ret.IsError=true;
          ret.Error=ex.Message;                
     }

     return ret;
 }
```

The idea is, when I read a subFile, it has to be serialized inside its main file, and this is made with recursivity.. the problem is that I dont find the "Base Case" to stop the recursivation and I´m getting crazy...

Any help would be great for me... 
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you specifically said not to serialize your subfiles with `[XmlIgnore]` tag.  Remove that tag, and you should see your subfiles (you may need to tweak your datatypes - I don't remember if `List<>` is serializable or not...

Comment: Hi LB2 thanks for your fast answer, each file has different attribute like <name>, <version> , <description>, and more stuff which change if its a main or a subfile.. I need to serialize the content of each file, and if file is a subfile, it has to be returned in the same object...

Comment: @minoyo Unfortunately I couldn't follow your comment.  If you don't want subfile properties serialized, then mark those as ignored.  Alternatively, if you don't want ot include subfile attributes, but just file content, you can keep your ignore as is, and in your main file create a property that returns subfile's content, and serialize it.  On the setter of the property, when contents are assigned to it by deserializer, write it so that it recreates subfile class and all attributes of it from text.